# onCreateView() wait for AsyncTask to execute?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is my situation:

In my `onCreate()`, I would like to create an `AsyncTask` to retrieve data for a server and store it in an `ArrayList`.

Then in my `onCreateView()`, I would like to put that data in a `ListView`, set an `onItemClickListener`, etc...

The problem is that I am creating a race between the `AsyncTask` and the UI thread.  If the `onCreateView()` is called before the `AsyncTask` is done retrieving, then I do not set the adapter correctly, do not set the `onItemClickListener`, etc...

I would like some way to make sure that I wait for the `AsyncTask` to finish executing before starting the `onCreateView()` function.  Is this possible?  I read about using `get()` on the task, but I had some trouble executing it.  It didn't seem to be doing anything.

The reason I would like to retrieve the data in `onCreate()` and set the adapter in `onCreateView()` (instead of setting the adapter in `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`), is that I would like to retrieve the data once, and be able to just create the view if the user rotates the screen or navigates back to that `Fragment`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a better way. Initialize your `ListView` and start your `AsyncTask` in `onCreate()`. Once data is available from the server, you add it to the same array which was given to your adapter and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` of your adapter, which takes care of populating your list view. Here you can use `ListFragment` as well in which you can call `setEmptyText()` to add text that is displayed if your list is empty.

Comment: oh interesting. Do i have to setOnItemClickListener() every time i update the adapter? or just once at the beginning? Also, how can i initialize the listview in onCreate() if the view hasn't been created yet? wouldn't that give me a nullpointerexception?

Comment: you have to set `OnItemClickListenter` only once. To initialize list view when there is no data, just use an `ArrayList` with no elements. It won't give any NullPointerException. Later when data arrived you can add that to the same `ArrayList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: thanks! works great! one quick question about the `OnItemClickListener` comment: If i only have the `setOnItemClickListener` call in `onCreateView()`, it doesn't seem to work.  But if i add another call to `setOnItemClickListener` after I update the adapter, it works.  This isn't really a big deal since it is working this way, but I would like to know why this could happen if you have any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: You don't show any code, but if I had to guess, it is getting garbage collected because you no longer hold a reference to it.  Are you using `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`?

Comment: So do I have to inflate my View in onCreate()? I obviously need the view to find ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow @sujith's answer and change your implementation, but here is an answer to your specific question:

> I would like some way to make sure that I wait for the AsyncTask to
>   finish executing before starting the onCreateView() function. Is this
>   possible?

Yes this is possible, but it will prevent your UI from displaying while it is waiting for the task to finish.

Create and execute your `AsyncTask` then hold on to the reference to it:

```
MyAsyncTask mTask;

...
...onCreate()
mTask = new MyAsyncTask();
mTask.execute();
...
...onCreateView()
myInfo = mTask.get();
super.onCreateView().
```

In your case this is a bad idea, however, there are times when you may need to do something like this.

EDIT: `mTask.get()` will return whatever is returned by the `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing in `onCreateView()`, move it to `onViewCreated()`

`onViewCreated` is invoked after view is ready so you will not have problems then